# Merge issues contributing to a github repo with 100s of contributors

Tags: git, github, commit, git-merge, pull-request

I tried to commit to a public github repo, basically what I did was:

```
- Fork the project's (Master branch)
- Made my changes and pushed to my forked repo (Master)
- Created a merge request to the original repo (Master)
```

The repo is set to automates merges (in absence of conflicts and issues), but I'm confused get the following auto commit message:

> Please read and remove:
>
> Practically all PRs are non-mergeable because they conflict with each
> other, and continually asking for rebases would be impractical.
>
> Because of that, it is likely that your signature is added via a
> commit that references and closes the PR, rather than a regular merge.
> I have a supervised script that processes the patches and commits them
> individually, referencing their origin PR for credit and authenticity.
> In such case, you'll see said commit linked in the notification email
> and in the page of the PR itself.

while I waited for my pull request to be accepted, others have contributed. So now there are merge conflicts.
Should I pull again and re-introduce my changes? should I rebase?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ... while I waited for my pull request to be accepted, others has contributed. So now there are merge conflicts. Should I pull again and re-introduce my changes?

No: at least, I think that's what the original fellow meant.  Let's call him Bob, so that we can assign human actors, and I will then paraphrase to make the actions clearer (in my opinion).  Bob said:

*By the time I, Bob, get around to looking at your pull request, it will probably have merge conflicts.  I won't ask you to rebase your changes.  Instead, I'll fuss with them myself to make them go in.  Eventually I'll make my own commit, or commits, and I'll put your name in them and put a link in them to your original pull request.  So what goes into my repository will have the same effect as your pull request, but won't actually be your commits.*

> should I rebase?

Not unless Bob specifically asks you to.

Comment: Thanks for the translation. But is this a recommended work flow for projects with a large number of contributors? if not, what is?

Comment: I don't think it's a long-term-sustainable flow for such projects. For instance, Git itself, and the Linux kernel, have a loose hierarchy with "one guy in charge at the top" who does the final merges but a large number of people one step down who manage subsystems, and *they* direct people even further down to make changes and rebase as appropriate.

Comment: Yeah I can imagine with such huge projects. Thanks again